# type mismatch - это что?

Tags: pascal

В общем объявлен массив

> a array [2..10^6] of integer

Программа выдает эту ошибку на строку SetLength(a,n); 
n - мы вводим с клавиатуры.

Comment: type mismatch - несовпадение типов. В данном случае, компилятор говорит вам, что SetLength() в качестве первого параметра принимает динамический массив (объявляется без указания размерности), а вы передаете статический (с фиксированной размерностью).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используется Setlength(), то размерность массива не ставится.

```
a: array of integer
```

Потому как если Вы указываете размерность - массив статический, под него выделено место в памяти при старте программы, а если динамический - место в памяти выделяется после указания размерности.